# What is the most effective ViewModel strategy?

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel, android-viewmodel

Okay so I'm asking this question after reading the docs and doing the codelabs.

The docs use a shared `ViewModel` and the codelabs don't.

Is it more memory intensive using a shared model when calling said model from fragments?

Conversely if I associate fragments with their own model does that follow best practice? I noticed that sometimes best practice doesn't always align with efficiency.

Comment: What docs are you talking about? The [Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide) talks specifically about screen specific viewmodels, same with the [saving state with fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state#nonconfig).

Answer (score 0):

Best answer would be it depends on project need i.e.
If two (or more) fragments share same kind of data then use shared viewmodel and if both fragments share different kind of data then go with individual viewmodel.
Still, individual viewmodel is best practice but in the end it all depends on our need.